# Why I can't I book a date for my UK Visa appointment?

Tags: visas, uk

I am planning to go to UK in the mid of December for a visit. Currently, I want to book for my visa appointment on early of November, however, I can't click any date in November. The only available ones are to book a date in October. I wonder that how it would be possible that there still are so many available options to book a date in October and no options at all in November. Can anyone enlighten me about this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It could be that they don't allow to schedule appointments so far in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience of making two applications, the furthest in advance you can book is around 21 days. Both times I’ve booked an initial date just to get my application into the system as early as possible, then I’ve changed the booked appointment date online as soon as further dates become available.